# MyBB URL rewrite won't work

Tags: url, http-status-code-404, friendly-url, mybb

I'm trying to enable URL rewrite on my MyBB board, i enabled it in Admin CP and i put default .htaccess file which come with board into my forum root but when i try to access thread, it returns: The requested URL /thread-86-lastpost.html was not found on this server.
404 Not Found

What i should do in order to fix it?
I think problem is in my apache2.conf file, but i do not known how to fix it.

Forum is hosted on my Debian VPS where i have Apache2 installed with PHP and All other stuff. LAMP

My .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

#
# If mod_security is enabled, attempt to disable it.
# - Note, this will work on the majority of hosts but on
#   MediaTemple, it is known to cause random Internal Server
#   errors. For MediaTemple, please remove the block below
#
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    # Turn off mod_security filtering.
    SecFilterEngine Off

    # The below probably isn't needed, but better safe than sorry.
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

#
# MyBB "search engine friendly" URL rewrites
# - Note, for these to work with MyBB please make sure you have
#   the setting enabled in the Admin CP and you have this file
#   named .htaccess
#
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-lastpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=lastpost [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextnewest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextnewest [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextoldest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextoldest [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-newpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=newpost [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&pid=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^announcement-([0-9]+)\.html$ announcements.php?aid=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^user-([0-9]+)\.html$ member.php?action=profile&uid=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=yearview&calendar=$1&year=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)-day-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=dayview&calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3&day=$4 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-week-(n?[0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=weekview&calendar=$1&week=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^event-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=event&eid=$1 [L,QSA]

    <IfModule mod_env.c>
        SetEnv SEO_SUPPORT 1
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

#
# If Apache is compiled with built in mod_deflade/GZIP support
# then GZIP Javascript, CSS, HTML and XML so they're sent to
# the client faster.
#
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript text/css text/html text/xml
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try the Google SEO plugin: http://mods.mybb.com/view/google-seo

It's much easier to use, and creates great SEO for your board.

Comment: I using it. Problem was in my apache rewrite module. NOw everything works-